# On some loci of rings

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra

Let $(R, \mathfrak m)$ be a Noetherian local ring. Let P be a property of $R$. Set
$$ P(R) =\{\mathfrak p \in Spec(R)\,\,\, |\,\,\, R_{\mathfrak p}\, \, \mbox{is } P\},$$
$$ nP(R) =\{\mathfrak p \in Spec(R)\,\,\, |\,\,\, R_{\mathfrak p}\, \, \mbox{is not} P\}.$$
I knew that:

(1) If  $R$ is excellent ring then $P(R)$ is open, where P is "regular";

(2) If $R$ is homomorphic image of a Gorenstein ring then $P(R)$ is open, where P is "Gorenstein".

The methods: Using Topological Nagata criterion and Ring theoretic Nagata criterion.
In these cases $nP(R)$ is closed.

**My question:** Find $I$, $J$ so that $nP(R)=Var(I)$ in Case 1 and $nP(R)=Var(J)$ in Case 2.
Thank you for your comment or answer for me!

Comment: I don't know an algorithm for 1, if you are finite type over a perfect field you can use the Jacobian, or see the recent work of Hochster-Jeffries.  For 2, there are options.  First, a ring is Gorenstein if and only if it is Cohen-Macaulay with locally free canonical module.  The non-Cohen-Macaulay locus can be expressed as the vanishing of the annihilator of certain Ext groups.  The locus where the canonical module $\omega_R$ is not locally free can be computed in various ways (from homological, to in the case of a reduced ring, via a map $\omega_R \cdot \omega_R^{-1} \to R$).

Comment: Thank @KarlSchwede very much for your comment. I understand the second part now.